# Is this possible to call the System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url in C# Models function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url

I want the asp.net mvc domain in my C# code (model function). I trying to call this function on string but it's not worked.

```
 string domain = "" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
```

When I tried to call same in controller's actionresult then this work but in c# models it's not work.

I hope the context will make it work but it's not worked.

Someone please explain me if something else I can use. What I want to do is getting url and I want to not pass the url (domain) form every call.

Answer (score 2):

`HttpContext.Current` will only work if the code is executed within an existing HTTP context. For example this code will return null if you attempt to execute it in a unit test. It is a terribly bad practice to rely on any HttpContext specific things in your models. This property could be set in your controller (where you have access to the HttpContext) and then pass the model to your DAL and Service layers where the property will already be populated.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your context / models, it might not be available.  This being said, you can pass the context in, or at least the url as a parameter to the model in need.